# XSD/JAXB: Sequence of multiple elements bounded by elements with the same name

Tags: jaxb, xsd, sequences

My model element may contain several child elements of different types. For each type, only 0 or 1 child elements may be present. The order of these elements is defined, i.e. all elements of type A come before B etc. My model class, generated by JAXB, should therefore have a separate getter/setter property for each type of child element.

What complicates things is the one exception to the above rule: At the beginning and near the end of the list of child elements there may each appear 0 or 1 elements of type X, and these elements both have the same name.

Here's a slightly simplified version of my current real life XSD type:

```
<xs:complexType name="Activity">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="log" type="DiagnosticLogMessage" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
        <xs:element name="inputs" type="Mappings" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
        <xs:element name="outputs" type="Mappings" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
        <xs:element name="log" type="DiagnosticLogMessage" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
        <xs:element name="to" type="DirectConnection" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

"log" is the problematic element. With the above type definition, "to" correctly gets its own property, but the remaining elements go into a list named "logsAndInputsAndOutputs". If I rename the two "log" elements to "logBefore" and "logAfter", each elements gets its own property, so clearly the problem is that JAXB cannot differentiate between the two "log"s.

I understand that the XSD itself is not really exact: It allows a single child element of type "log", in which case it's undefined if this is to be considered the "before" or the "after" element. In my current (manually written) reader class I have explicit code to detect this case and interpret a single "log" element as the "before" element.

I'm looking for a way to tell JAXB to treat the two "log" elements differently, either via xjb mappings or possibly with a more specific XSD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

Below is how you could handle this use case by leveraging MOXy's `@XmlPath` extension.

**XML Schema (schema.xsd)**

Here is an XML schema based on the fragment you have provided in your question.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    targetNamespace="urn:forum17408865" xmlns="urn:forum17408865"
    elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <xs:element name="foo">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="bar" type="Activity"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:complexType name="Activity">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="log" type="DiagnosticLogMessage"
                minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
            <xs:element name="inputs" type="Mappings" minOccurs="0"
                maxOccurs="1" />
            <xs:element name="outputs" type="Mappings" minOccurs="0"
                maxOccurs="1" />
            <xs:element name="log" type="DiagnosticLogMessage"
                minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
            <xs:element name="to" type="DirectConnection" minOccurs="0"
                maxOccurs="1" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="DiagnosticLogMessage" />

    <xs:complexType name="Mappings" />

    <xs:complexType name="DirectConnection" />

</xs:schema>
```

**Activity**

MOXy has an `@XmlPath` extension that allows you to map to an XML element based on its position.  This class can't be generated from the XML schema so we will create it ourselves.

```java
package forum17408865;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.XmlPath;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(propOrder={"log1", "inputs", "outputs", "log2", "to"})
public class Activity {

    @XmlPath("log[1]")
    private DiagnosticLogMessage log1;

    private Mappings inputs;

    private Mappings outputs;

    @XmlPath("log[2]")
    private DiagnosticLogMessage log2;

    private DirectConnection to;

}
```

**binding.xml**

To have JAXB use the class we created manually we will leverage a JAXB bindings file.

```
<jxb:bindings xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" version="2.1">

    <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="schema.xsd">
        <jxb:bindings node="//xs:complexType[@name='Activity']">
            <jxb:class ref="forum17408865.Activity" />
        </jxb:bindings>
    </jxb:bindings>

</jxb:bindings>
```

**XJC Call**

Below is the XJC call that leverages the bindings file.  Note how we also needed to use the `-nv` flag to disable schema validation.

```
xjc -nv -b binding.xml schema.xs
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/07/xpath-based-mapping.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/specifying-eclipselink-moxy-as-your.html

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I had tried using XPath indexes in my JAXB bindings file, but XJC couldn't differentiate between them.
It would be even nicer if I could specify the XmlPath properties in my bindings XML and get autocreated classes, but for now I have no problems generating classes from a slightly simplified schema and then copying and manually modifying them to my static sourecs.